# using cmake with QT class

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to compile dll with cmake, using QT class. My CmakeLists.txt:

```
project(modules)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
....
set(HEADERS renderwindow.h)
QT_WRAP_CPP(modules LIB_HEADER_MOC ${HEADERS})
...
add_library(modules SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${LIB_HEADER_MOC})

target_link_libraries(modules Qt5::Gui)
```

And during link proccess I get error "undefined reference" to class member.

```
C:/projects/kurs/triangles/modules/renderwindow.cpp:11: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QBitmapC1Ev'
C:/projects/kurs/triangles/modules/renderwindow.cpp:13: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN7QBitmapC1Eii'
```

Where is the error in CMakeList.txt?

Comment: What version of cmake are you using?

Comment: @Nicolas Holthaus cmake v 3.3.2